# How to add UIGestureRecognizer to drawed arcs, elipses, line etc?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I have crated "ball" using CGContextAddArc. My idea is to add tap and pan gestures to it.

```
- (void)drawBallAtPoint:(CGPoint)centerPoint inContext:(CGContextRef)context {
    UIGraphicsPushContext(context);
    CGContextBeginPath(context);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, centerPoint.x,centerPoint.y);
    CGContextAddArc(context, centerPoint.x, centerPoint.y, 30, 0.0, 2*M_PI, NO);    CGContextFillPath(context);
    UIGraphicsPopContext();
}
```

I know how to tell is currently touch on that "ball", but that works only in tap gesture.

```
- (BOOL)isPointInBall:(CGPoint)point {
    CGRect ballTouchRect = CGRectMake(self.ballCenterPoint.x - kBallRadius, self.ballCenterPoint.y - kBallRadius, kBallRadius*2, kBallRadius*2);
    return CGRectContainsPoint(ballTouchRect, point);
}
```

In panGesture it doesn't work properly

```
- (void)panGestureHappened:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panGestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint tapLocation = [panGestureRecognizer locationInView:self];
    if ([self isPointInBall:tapLocation]) {
         self.canBETouched = YES;
        NSLog(@"START");
    }
    switch (panGestureRecognizer.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:{
            self.touched = YES;
            NSLog(@"BEGAN");

            break;
        }
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged: {

            if (self.canBETouched) {


                CGFloat radius = [self sliderRadius];
                CGPoint sliderCenter = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2);
                CGPoint sliderStartPoint = CGPointMake(sliderCenter.x, sliderCenter.y - radius);
                CGFloat angle = angleBetweenThreePoints(sliderCenter, sliderStartPoint, tapLocation);

                if (angle < 0) {
                    angle = -angle;
                }
                else {
                    angle = 2*M_PI - angle;
                }

                self.value = translateValueFromSourceIntervalToDestinationInterval(angle, 0, 2*M_PI, self.minimumValue, self.maximumValue);
            }

            break;
        }
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:{
            self.touched = NO;
            self.canBETouched = NO;

            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

It works only, if touch begans out of "ball" and then and then it slides inside in "ball". it not responds, if touch began in "ball".

So, how can I add panGesture only on this ball?

Comment: Are you saying that you don't see any `START` logs when you start the pan inside the circle?!? I find that hard to believe, but you can confirm by logging `ballTouchRect` and `point` and diagnose where it's going wrong. Incidentally, the call to `isPointInBall` would generally be done inside the `UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan` block, but that seems academic.

Comment: BTW, I'm confused by the fact that you're drawing the circle at `centerPoint`, but using `ballCenterPoint` for your hit test, and using `sliderCenter` when calculating your ARC in the gesture recognizer. I don't understand the relation b/w these three `CGPoint` values.

Comment: this "ball" is slider thumb.

Comment: OK. Can you tell us what your pan gesture recognizer is supposed to be doing (I'm having a hard time reconciling the "slider" terminology with the calculation of the angle between three points). But, if you want the ball to move, you have to (a) have your gesture recognizer change `ballCenterPoint`; and (b) have gesture recognizer call `setNeedsDisplay` so that your `drawRect` (which presumably call your circle drawing method) will be called. I'm not seeing these aspects to your gesture recognizer, so I don't see how it could work.